# How to add layers to RNN Encoder-Decoder network in SeqToSeq demo for Paddle?

Tags: python, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, paddle-paddle, encoder-decoder

I'm trying to add an additional encoder and decoder layers to the RNN SeqToSeq network in the `paddle-paddle` [text generation demo](http://www.paddlepaddle.org/doc/demo/text_generation/text_generation.html) like in the GNMT paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08144v2.pdf

[image]

At the code point (https://github.com/baidu/Paddle/blob/master/demo/seqToseq/seqToseq_net.py#L100), I added an additional layer:

```
src_word_id = data_layer(name='source_language_word', size=source_dict_dim)
src_embedding = embedding_layer(
    input=src_word_id,
    size=word_vector_dim,
    param_attr=ParamAttr(name='_source_language_embedding'))
src_forward = simple_gru(input=src_embedding, size=encoder_size)
src_backward = simple_gru(input=src_embedding,
                          size=encoder_size,
                          reverse=True)
encoded_vector_0 = concat_layer(input=[src_forward, src_backward])

with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size) as encoded_proj_0:
    encoded_proj_0 += full_matrix_projection(input=encoded_vector_0)

encoded_proj_1 = fc_layer(input=[encoded_proj_0, encoded_vector_0], size=decoder_size * 3)

encoded_vector = pooling_layer(input=grumemory(input=encoded_proj_1), pooling_type=MaxPooling())

with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size) as encoded_proj:
    encoded_proj +=full_matrix_projection(input=encoded_vector)


backward_first = first_seq(input=src_backward)
```

And because the output of the 2nd layer encoder is no longer a sequence, I had to unset the `is_sequence` flag at https://github.com/baidu/Paddle/blob/master/demo/seqToseq/seqToseq_net.py#L131, i.e.:

```
decoder_group_name = "decoder_group"
group_inputs=[StaticInput(input=encoded_vector),
              StaticInput(input=encoded_proj)]
```

The full code I've tried is at https://gist.github.com/alvations/c86c82d935ac6ef37c472d19232ebbb6

**How to add layers to RNN Encoder-Decoder network in SeqToSeq demo for Paddle?**

One related question too, if I were to add a layer at the encoder, would it be compulsory to add a layer also at the decoder end?

Another thing is the sequence issue. After passing through multi layered RNN, the sequence no longer exist, is that alright? Or am I stacking the layers wrongly?

---

## Edited

I've tried something like this and it trains and saves the model and I'm able to decode (i.e. generate) new translations but somehow the scores were much lower than using a single layer bidirectional GRU.

```
def minion_encoder_decoder(data_conf,
                        is_generating,
                        word_vector_dim=512,
                        encoder_size=512,
                        decoder_size=512,
                        beam_size=3,
                        max_length=250):
    """
    A wrapper for an attention version of GRU Encoder-Decoder network
    is_generating: whether this config is used for generating
    encoder_size: dimension of hidden unit in GRU Encoder network
    decoder_size: dimension of hidden unit in GRU Decoder network
    word_vector_dim: dimension of word vector
    beam_size: expand width in beam search
    max_length: a stop condition of sequence generation
    """
    for k, v in data_conf.iteritems():
        globals()[k] = v
    source_dict_dim = len(open(src_dict_path, "r").readlines())
    target_dict_dim = len(open(trg_dict_path, "r").readlines())
    gen_trans_file = gen_result

    if decoder_size % 3 != 0:
        decoder_size = decoder_size / 3 * 3

    src_word_id = data_layer(name='source_language_word', size=source_dict_dim)
    src_embedding = embedding_layer(
        input=src_word_id,
        size=word_vector_dim,
        param_attr=ParamAttr(name='_source_language_embedding'))
    src_forward = simple_gru(input=src_embedding, size=encoder_size)
    src_backward = simple_gru(input=src_embedding,
                              size=encoder_size,
                              reverse=True)
    encoded_vector = concat_layer(input=[src_forward, src_backward])

    with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size) as encoded_proj:
        encoded_proj += full_matrix_projection(input=encoded_vector)

    input_layers = [encoded_proj, encoded_vector] # Bidirectional GRU layer.
    for i in range(6):
        encoded_proj = fc_layer(input=input_layers, size=decoder_size)
        encoded_vector = grumemory(input=encoded_proj,
                                    layer_attr=ExtraAttr(drop_rate=0.1))
        input_layers = [encoded_proj, encoded_vector]

    backward_first = first_seq(input=encoded_vector)
    with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size,
                     act=TanhActivation(), ) as decoder_boot:
        decoder_boot += full_matrix_projection(input=backward_first)


    def gru_decoder_with_attention(enc_vec, enc_proj, current_word):
        decoder_mem = memory(name='gru_decoder',
                             size=decoder_size,
                             boot_layer=decoder_boot)

        context = simple_attention(encoded_sequence=enc_vec,
                                   encoded_proj=enc_proj,
                                   decoder_state=decoder_mem, )

        with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size * 3) as decoder_inputs:
            decoder_inputs += full_matrix_projection(input=context)
            decoder_inputs += full_matrix_projection(input=current_word)

        gru_step = gru_step_layer(name='gru_decoder',
                                  input=decoder_inputs,
                                  output_mem=decoder_mem,
                                  size=decoder_size)

        with mixed_layer(size=target_dict_dim,
                         bias_attr=True,
                         act=SoftmaxActivation()) as out:
            out += full_matrix_projection(input=gru_step)
            for i in range(8):
                out += full_matrix_projection(input=gru_step)
        return out

    decoder_group_name = "decoder_group"
    group_inputs=[StaticInput(input=encoded_vector, is_seq=True),
                  StaticInput(input=encoded_proj, is_seq=True)]

    if not is_generating:
        trg_embedding = embedding_layer(
            input=data_layer(name='target_language_word',
                             size=target_dict_dim),
            size=word_vector_dim,
            param_attr=ParamAttr(name='_target_language_embedding'))
        group_inputs.append(trg_embedding)

        # For decoder equipped with attention mechanism, in training,
        # target embeding (the groudtruth) is the data input,
        # while encoded source sequence is accessed to as an unbounded memory.
        # Here, the StaticInput defines a read-only memory
        # for the recurrent_group.
        decoder = recurrent_group(name=decoder_group_name,
                                  step=gru_decoder_with_attention,
                                  input=group_inputs)

        lbl = data_layer(name='target_language_next_word',
                         size=target_dict_dim)
        cost = classification_cost(input=decoder, label=lbl)
        outputs(cost)
    else:
        # In generation, the decoder predicts a next target word based on
        # the encoded source sequence and the last generated target word.

        # The encoded source sequence (encoder's output) must be specified by
        # StaticInput, which is a read-only memory.
        # Embedding of the last generated word is automatically gotten by
        # GeneratedInputs, which is initialized by a start mark, such as <s>,
        # and must be included in generation.

        trg_embedding = GeneratedInput(
            size=target_dict_dim,
            embedding_name='_target_language_embedding',
            embedding_size=word_vector_dim)
        group_inputs.append(trg_embedding)

        beam_gen = beam_search(name=decoder_group_name,
                               step=gru_decoder_with_attention,
                               input=group_inputs,
                               bos_id=0,
                               eos_id=1,
                               beam_size=beam_size,
                               max_length=max_length)

        seqtext_printer_evaluator(input=beam_gen,
                                  id_input=data_layer(name="sent_id", size=1),
                                  dict_file=trg_dict_path,
                                  result_file=gen_trans_file)
        outputs(beam_gen)
```

Most part of the code is the same as the demo code in Paddle but I've added these.

At the encoder:

```
src_word_id = data_layer(name='source_language_word', size=source_dict_dim)
src_embedding = embedding_layer(
    input=src_word_id,
    size=word_vector_dim,
    param_attr=ParamAttr(name='_source_language_embedding'))
src_forward = simple_gru(input=src_embedding, size=encoder_size)
src_backward = simple_gru(input=src_embedding,
                          size=encoder_size,
                          reverse=True)
encoded_vector = concat_layer(input=[src_forward, src_backward])

with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size) as encoded_proj:
    encoded_proj += full_matrix_projection(input=encoded_vector)

input_layers = [encoded_proj, encoded_vector] # Bidirectional GRU layer.
for i in range(6):
    encoded_proj = fc_layer(input=input_layers, size=decoder_size)
    encoded_vector = grumemory(input=encoded_proj,
                                layer_attr=ExtraAttr(drop_rate=0.1))
    input_layers = [encoded_proj, encoded_vector]

backward_first = first_seq(input=encoded_vector)
with mixed_layer(size=decoder_size,
                 act=TanhActivation(), ) as decoder_boot:
    decoder_boot += full_matrix_projection(input=backward_first)
```

At the decoder:

```
    with mixed_layer(size=target_dict_dim,
                     bias_attr=True,
                     act=SoftmaxActivation()) as out:
        out += full_matrix_projection(input=gru_step)
        for i in range(8):
            out += full_matrix_projection(input=gru_step)
    return out
```

I'm still unsure whether I'm stacking the layers correctly.

Comment: At the decoder, that's wrong, that's basically only propagating within every timestep the fully connected layer (activation)

Comment: https://github.com/baidu/Paddle/issues/504#issuecomment-261170778